# Unable to get relative path in IntelliJ for resource file - Java/Selenium

Tags: java, intellij-idea, relative-path, intellij-14

I am struggling with getting a relative path to a file in a resource folder.
I have spent hours pouring over and attempting other resolutions in other threads, but have failed, I don't know whether due to the exact syntax being wrong, but I would really appreciate some help with exactly what to write.
Screenshot is attached

**File setup**

I run my tests from my class TestRunner which goes to PropertiesUtil to get the browser to run the tests in, from the config.properties file.

The config.properties file is in a resources folder but I am unable to get to the config file using a relative path. It works fine as an absolute, but that means it fails when someone else runs it.

If I do attempt other paths, I get the error:

```
2019-03-06 21:21:16 INFO  TestRunner - Before running
java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
```

Please help! I've spent far too long stuck on this.

[image: structure]

Tried with ClassLoader as suggested but this doesn't work in propertiesUtil nor am I quite sure how to write it in conjunction with what I have (as it complained about static/non-static). On running from TestRunner to try and debug and understand, it doesn't give me much useful information.
[ClassLoader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymsUA.png)

I also tried a similar thing I saw elsewhere. Same issue:
[non-static to static error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt3H9.png)

Comment: `"../resources/config.properties"` and `"../../resources/config.properties"` didn't work?

Comment: yes I tried both of those before posting :( and got: 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ../../resources/config.properties (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this.

```
   public static void readPropertiesFiles() {
        ClassLoader classLoader = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader();
        String path = classLoader.getResource("config.properties").getPath();
        System.out.println(path);
    }
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to have helped, I wasn't able to put it in the PropertiesUtil file and when I used debug to inspect it, it didn't give me any path or anything. I'm not very clear how to use the ClassLoader with the input stream

Comment: didnt realize the method was static, i updated the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Amazing!! That works brilliantly. For reference to anyone finding this - this is a screenshot of the code now with the above fix!

[Working code now implemented](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibZZF.png)